# How to insert instructional text that disappear only when you write something?

Tags: excel, vba, text

I'm working on an Excel sheets that will have text in the background or that disappear when you click on it, so that it display instructions for the person who will use it.

I've found a code but you can't add text that won't disappear, which is a problem for me. Is there a way that the text can be in the background and disappear when you enter a new text that will stil be there even if you click on it, maybe like watermark but that disappear ?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
listecellules = "/" & Range("C9").Address & "/" & Range("C10").Address & "/" & Range("C18").Address & "/" & Range("C26").Address & "/" & Range("C32").Address & "/"
If listecellules Like "*/" & Target.Address & "/*" Then
If Target <> "" Then
texte = Target.Value
Target = ""
temps_début = Timer
    Do While Timer < temps_début + 1
        DoEvents
    Loop
If Target = "" Then
Target.Value = texte
End If
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What about Data validation? Where there is text that appears only when you click on the relevant cell?

Comment: It's not an optimal solution for the purpose of the sheet. It would be better to have text in the background that dissapear when you click or write on it.

Comment: Appears when you click on it, then disappears when you enter a text or value - what more do you want?

Comment: If you use the worksheet change event, you could have the place holder text in the cell, once you started typing it would obviously be replace, if you cleared the target, the place holder can show again

Comment: The problem is that the text always disappear, this code is made for writing text that will disappear, but I need a code on which the text you wrote won't dissapear, it's just that there's already a text in the cell that will disappear as you write the new permanent text.

Answer (score 0):

I found a code that is acceptable :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Count = 1 Then
    Dim Colr As Long, Txt As String
    If Target.Address(0, 0) = "D3" Then
      Txt = "Enter Last Name Here"
    ElseIf Target.Address(0, 0) = "D4" Then
      Txt = "Enter First Name Here"
   End If

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Len(Target.Value) = 0 Or Target.Value = Txt Then
      Target.Font.ColorIndex = 16
      Target.Value = Txt
    Else
      Target.Font.ColorIndex = 1
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
  End If

End Sub
```